# Communicating cross-origin from parent to child iframe

Tags: javascript, html, postmessage

I'm working through [Third Party Javascript](//thirdpartyjs.com). I'm particularly interested in communication between a parent page and a child frame from a different origin. Using window.postMessage, it's trivial to safely send messages from the child and have the parent receive them with the `message` event.

I have had no luck going the other direction. Can I get some confirmation that it is *not* possible to communicate from the parent to the child using postMessage? If not what are ways of working around this problem?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You should be able to use `.postMessage()` between any two cooperating windows.  It doesn't matter which direction you are sending the message.  If it is not working in one direction, then there is probably an error in the implementation.  You may need to make sure you have the proper window object.

For an iframe, you would want to use the `.contentWindow` property to get its window in modern browsers.

Some good documentation here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.postMessage

Comment: You were so correct. My implementation had a bug in it that I only saw after posting.

Comment: any chance you know how to get the .contentWindow property? I don't seem to have one on the iframe in my page. Same domain too...

Comment: This was monumentally useful for me. Thank you!