# Content of iframe not opening in iframe only

Tags: javascript, html, redirect, iframe

I have a base page in which am using a Iframe of different domain.
Content gets render but if user click on any link rendered inside iframe it get open as normal page.
I want it to be opened in Iframe only.

for information, I can control my base page as well as application hosted on different domain.. which i want to so in iframe.

In simple words whole site that is opened in iframe, user should be able to do his work in iframe only. click on any link inside iframe should not open in browser. so that I can create a central application which can open my application(Existing) in iframe. As well as if user open the application seperatly it can also work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Technically, you could use .postmessage() to get the child content inside the iframe to send a message to the parent to change the iframe source on button clicks.

Note, this will only work if you have control of the child code getting rendered inside the iframe, which I cannot tell from your question.

Example, in your child site, inside the iframe, it would need code to send to the parent page (outside the iframe) when you click INSIDE the iframe site:

```
self.parent.postMessage("stringSayingDoSomething", "*");
```

Then, your parent site has an event listener set up to receive the message and perform an action.. that action can be doing something on the parent side.. or, sending a message back down to the child site to do something instead:

```
window.addEventListener("message", receiveMessage, false);
            function receiveMessage(event) {

                switch (message) {
                    case "stringSayingDoSomething":
                        DoMyFunctionNowThatChildFrameHasToldMeTo();
                        break;
```

Here is another question on stack overflow addressing the issue:  [Communicating cross-origin from parent to child iframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19011780/communicating-cross-origin-from-parent-to-child-iframe)

Comment: I have control over the site getting rendered inside iframe but it is very complex site. Could you share some snippet that I need to put in site

Answer (score 1):

If you don't have access to the code of the iFrame page you won't have a chance of doing this.

See: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_scripting